# Java. Постоянное сетевое соединение

Tags: java, сеть

Пишу пошаговую стратегию на Java с количеством игроков от 2 до 4. Интересует вопрос, как реализовать связь между клиентами и сервером.

На данный момент работает все так. Первое приложение "сервер" ждет запросов от других клиентов. Второе приложение "клиент" подключается к "серверу", игрок заносится в список. Что то происходит на игровом поле, "сервер" сохраняет состояние, "клиент" каждую секунду отправляет запрос состояния. Сделано все на Socket и ServerSocket.

Итоговый результат меня не устраивает, подскажите как реализовать или дайте направление куда смотреть, что бы все было примерно так:

Приложение "Сервер" ждет игроков ("Сервер" и сам является игроком), "клиент" подключается, игрок на "сервере" делает ход, жмет завершить ход. И оповещает об этом клиента/клиентов, что бы клиенты не запрашивали каждую секунду состояние игры.

P.S. Приложение десктопное с использованием JavaFX, запускается с обычного компьютера, ip сообщается другим игрокам.

> Вы все правильно описали в последнем абзаце. В чем вопрос? – Nofate

(Дополню) Я не знаю как сделать так, что бы клиенты слушали сервер. У меня реализовано так: клиент обращается к серверу, сервер ему отвечает и все. Т.е. после получения ответа от сервера, клиент не может знать об изменениях, если не обратится опять к серверу. А необходимо, что бы сервер рассылал клиентам информацию, а клиенты постоянно ждали сообщений от сервера. Игроков максимум 4, мне кажется можно держать 4 постоянных соединения на время игры. Я только взялся за это, знаний минимум, могу думать в неправильном направлении.

Comment: Вы все правильно описали в последнем абзаце. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Я не знаю как сделать так, что бы клиенты слушали сервер. У меня реализовано так: клиент обращается к серверу, сервер ему отвечает и все. Т.е. после получения ответа от сервера, клиент не может знать об изменениях, если не обратится опять к серверу.  А необходимо, что бы сервер рассылал клиентам информацию, а клиенты постоянно ждали сообщений от сервера. Игроков максимум 4, мне кажется можно держать 4 постоянных соединения на время игры. Я только взялся за это, знаний минимум, могу думать в неправильном направлении.

Comment: Все верно. Просто держите список с клиентскими сокетами на сервере и после действий одного игрока рассылайте сообщение об этом другим.

Comment: вставлю свои 5 копеек.Технологии котрые могут Вам пригодиться для реализации того что вы хотите: поведенческий шаблон ["Observer"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649896.aspx) ( класс java.util.Observer; и интерфейс java.util.Observable) и java.io.Serializable для упрошения io операций.Удачи